# How to format integers?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, number-formatting

I want the integer to move left as you add places instead of right.

```
input = 1
output = "1 "

input = 10
output = "10 "


input = 100
output = "100 "

input = 1234
output = "1234 "
```

---

**Not** like this:

```
input = 1234
output = " 1234"

input = 123456
output = " 123456"
```

Comment: Lol not at all, im sorry i dont know to to format these posts.

Comment: @MikeJuneBugCaptain Just click the `?` icon in the edit box. Note, you can click `edit` and change your post even now.

Comment: I think you'd get more useful answers if you put the code you have right now.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what you need but it looks like you are adding a single space at the end of the integer number in your string. You can simply do

```
int i = 1;
string result = i.ToString() + " ";
```

Comment: yeah or string.Format("{0} ", i);

Comment: @sylon, sure, there was an answer with string.Format thats why post this :)

Comment: Yea but that's some weird spacing formatting logic, when a trailing space will do.

Comment: @sylon, It isn't clear to me what the OP really needs, other than that its about readability, to me its more clear and just a different thing from `string.Fromat`

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.Format()` method with format specifiers, as described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/e5bc8093-5aaa-4d28-99e7-8b40bc58df3c

For example:

```
string.Format("{0,-4}", 123);
```

gives:

```
"123 "
```

Comment: Though now when I'm looking at your formatted question, I'm not really sure if you want this, and want to append single space character instead...